# Custom API controller always returns 404 not found

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have created a custom controller called AccountController within Identity Server:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.PolicyName)]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    public AccountController()
    {
        
    }

    [HttpGet("Signup")]
    public IActionResult Signup()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Added the following API Resource:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources => new List<ApiResource> {
        new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
    };
```

Added the API resource to configuration:

```
 builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                // https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/resources/api_scopes#authorization-based-on-scopes
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources); // HERE
```

Added the following to `program.cs`

```
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
```

And my client is as follows:

```
 new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client.web",

            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
            IncludeJwtId = true,

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret12345".Sha256())
            },
            RedirectUris = new []
            {
                "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
            },
            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api", 
                              IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName, // HERE
                              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
            },

        }
```

Yet no matter what I do, when I called `https://localhost:5001/api/account/signup` it always returns 404 not found when trying to hit the Account endpoint.  Can anyone spot what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you registered your controllers with the service collection and told the app to route to them, etc?

Comment: You are having an authentication issue using builder.Services.AddLocalApiAuthentication()  You may of turned on the Proxy and need to disable proxy.  You are using OAUTH2.  See : https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/

Comment: IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName doesn't even come back in the list of allowed scopes for the client.. so when I try and hit the endpoint I now get: Checking for expected scope IdentityServerApi failed

Answer (score 2):

The Identity Server App is nothing more than an ordinary Web App. So do not forget to set up routing and other needed configs in program.cs. Check the order of app.MapGet, app.UseEndpoints and app.UseRouting. It seems that you are using the conventional routing so I suggest putting app.UseRouting() before the two if both exists in program.cs. Example from program.cs of my web app project with Identity Server alongside other custom api controllers:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
app.UseCors();
app.Run();
```